# Issue with AFrame updating entity colour using colour picker (vanilla-picker)

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

## Summary

I am working on a simple app that allows users to view a entity with a texture using aFrame in a 3d room. I am using aFrame, HTML and vanilla JS as well as a library called vanilla-picker for the color picker.

https://aframe.io/
https://vanilla-picker.js.org/

At the min I have a texture applied to the background wall and I want to give the user the option to choose a custom colour as well from a colour picker then apply that colour, replacing the texture.

The logic all seems to be working and the colour attribute updates in the relevant place in the html once the function has been ran from the vanilla-picker library, however the colour seems to never be applied and it is stumping me a bit.

Is it something to do with having to 'update' aFrame that the colour should change? Or something wrong with the hex codes themselves (view attached image for console log example). I should say that the entity starts with a texture applied but you can see from the code onChange that I strip that out and then it should be applying the colour attribute which I would expect to just apply the colour automatically (as there is not texture there anymore)

Any help appreciated

Here is the code for the color picker / swap colours func in the main JS

### Code

JS Snippet

```
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
var picker = new Picker(parent);

picker.onChange = function(color) {
     var wallpapertex = document.querySelector('a-entity');
     const wallpapercolor = color.hex;  
     console.log(wallpapertex.getAttribute('color'));
     wallpapertex.setAttribute('material', 'src', '');
};

picker.onDone = function(color) {
     var wallpapertex = document.querySelector('a-entity');
     const wallpapercolor = color.hex;  
     console.log(wallpapercolor);
     wallpapertex.setAttribute('color', wallpapercolor);
   }
```

Images

### The App itself with color picker loading

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9zIT.jpg

### Console log output and html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUO85.jpg

I have tried looking at the hex codes and modding them with developer tab with no results

I have looked for an error or missing dependency and been unable to find anything (obviously) wrong.

Wondered if it having an applied texture at loadtime would affect it, but I don't see why it should, as I strip that off at first and that part works

this is the line which strips the texture off :
wallpapertex.setAttribute('material', 'src', '');

### Expected:

I expect the hex value to be applied to the primitive and to apply the colour change to be applied after the onDone function has been called (after pressing Enter)

### Actual Results

What actually happens is the onChange removes the texture and then then the onDone function updates the attribute for the primitive shape (the wall) it then however remains white instead of updating to the selected hex value even though the change has (on the surface in the html) been applied to the primitive.

Answer (score 0):

## Fix

I managed to fix this with the following code, I had just missed a few things
setattribute was missing material and I think passing the color through as a hex was not working so passed it through as an rgba string from vanilla-picker. Now fully working

```
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
var picker = new Picker(parent);

picker.onChange = function(color) {
    var wallpapertex = document.querySelector('a-entity');
    const wallpapercolor = color.rgbaString; // I passed through the colour from picker as an rgba value instead of hex  
    wallpapertex.setAttribute('material', 'src', '');
    // wallpapertex.setAttribute('color', wallpapercolor); /// I think this line was wrong I had missed material 
       wallpapertex.setAttribute('material', 'color', wallpapercolor); 
    };
```

The picker.onDone function is not required in this instance as the colour updates every time the picker colour changes now.

Hope that helps someone else who gets stuck with a similar problem!